# Swing - Displaying text and checkboxes in custom file open dialog

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to build a custom file open dialog using

```
class CustomOpenComponent extends JComponent implements PropertyChangeListener
...

final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setAccessory(new CustomOpenComponent(fc));
int returnVal = fc.showDialog(parent, title);
```

I want to display a couple of text boxes and a checkboxed list which will display information about the file that the user has currently selected using the open dialog.

I am having a tough time trying to figure out how to tell `CustomOpenComponent` to display text boxes and the checklists.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: `JFileChooser` will fire `SelectedFileChangedProperty` and `SelectedFilesChangedProperty` when ever the file selection is changed.

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to display text boxes and check boxes in my `CustomOpenComponent`.

Comment: Good, that's the clarification we needed...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: so do you have an answer for this problem?

Comment: Have you examined the example cited in [*How to Use File Choosers: Providing an Accessory Component*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#accessory)?

Comment: That depends, what information are you trying to fill your `CustomOpenComponent` with? And what problems (in particular) are you having...?

Comment: CustomOpenComponent is "just" another Swing component. You display text fields and checkboxes on it the same way you do with any other Swing component.